When is the map sending a boundary point to its outer normal vector continuous?
Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded domain and $\partial \Omega$ its boundary. Let $\nu$ be the map sending each point $x \in \partial\Omega$ to the unique outer normal vector at this point. I would like to know when the map $\nu$ is continuous.
This math.SE question asks a similar question and based on the answers it seems a sufficient condition is for the boundary to be $C^1$. Is this also a necessary condition? If not, what is the weakest requirement we can place on $\partial \Omega$ so that $\nu$ remains continuous?

What entitles you to say that there is a unique outward normal vector at each point?

@TedShifrin Yes you're right. I suppose I should specify that I'm considering sufficiently nice surfaces such that there is a unique outward normal (for which I guess it would be sufficient to assume a $C^1$ boundary?)

Even piecewise-$C^1$ hypersurfaces fail to have this property if there is a single point of discontinuity.

@TedShifrin Thanks, in that case I will strengthen my assumption to a connected $C^1$ boundary with no points of discontinuity.

Well I don’t see why you’ll be able to lower the regularity below $C^1$. Imagine that $\partial \Omega$ is locally given by the graph of a function (and $\Omega$ the region below the graph). To find the normal, or at the very least define the normal, we’re going to need to differentiate the function, and if we want the normal to be continuous, we need a continuous derivative. But, if you’re happy to work with a.e (relative to the surface measure) defined $\nu$, you can lower the regularity of the boundary to just Lipschitz.

@peek-a-boo This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.
